# Vertically aligning fixed height tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a table with fixed height and width cells, which I have accomplished through other posts, but now the content inside my cells seems to begin at the halfway mark.  As of now, the way I am achieving the fixed height is through:

\begin{tabular}[tl]{|p{2.25in}|p{2.25in}| @{}m{0pt}@{}}

with rows something like:

LEFT & RIGHT & \[3in]

but then the "LEFT" and "RIGHT" end up in the middle of the table.  Is there a way to make these begin at the top but maintain the fixed heights?

The following code is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12 pt,twoside]{letter}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in,
            inner=.2in,outer=.45in,bottom=.5in,top=.9in,headsep=.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\1}{\textbf{1}}
\newcommand{\2}{\textbf{2}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\huge \textbf{K \1-\2}}
\cfoot{1}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{tabular}[tl]{|p{2.25in}|p{2.25in}| @{}m{0pt}@{}}
\hline
\1a&\2a\\[0ex]
\hline

    LEFT TOP
    &
    RIGHT TOP

&\\[3in]
\hline
\1b&\2b\\[0ex]
\hline

    LEFT BOTTOM
    &
    RIGHT BOTTOM

&\\[3in]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: What will the content denoted by `LEFT`/`RIGHT` `TOP`/`BOTTOM` represent? Paragraph text? `tabular`-like structure? Or just a single line of text?

Comment: there will definitely be multiple lines and sometimes tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to place the content in each of the cells inside its own `minipage`. This way you can [fix both the width and height, as well as the vertical alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56891/5764) with respect to the other parts of the `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
  \hline
  1a & 2a \\
  \hline
    \begin{minipage}[t][3in]{2.25in}
      \strut Left top
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}[t][3in]{2.25in}
      \strut Right top
    \end{minipage} \\
  \hline
  1b & 2b \\
  \hline
    \begin{minipage}[t][3in]{2.25in}
      \strut Left bottom
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}[t][3in]{2.25in}
      \strut Right bottom
    \end{minipage} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The starting `\strut`s help ensure a proper baseline around the top/bottom of a `minipage`, since this is [a known issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764).

Comment: This may be relevant, but I'm not sure: [How to keep a constant baseline skip when using `minipage`s in tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/242121/5764)