# Vertically centered material in fixed height rows in tabular environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, minipage, parbox

The goal is to obtain a table with **fixed height** rows, and to place the material inside -certain- cells vertically centered.

Looking for a robust and simple way, I have worked on this idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\def\text{This is a text example inside a cell}

\newcommand{\cell}[2]{\parbox[t][#1][c]{4cm}{#2}}    % <- '4cm' fixed!
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|C|}
\hline
\text & \cell{2cm}{\text} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

(Similar to [this approach using `minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249290/vertically-aligning-fixed-height-tables).)

At this point, I would like to use the width of each column into my `\cell` command, in order to replace the fixed "4cm" definition by the generic column width values.

What I am looking for, if possible, is to get the "current" witdh column register used by *tabularx, tabular* or *array*, and to use it like an `\parbox` argument. This will also be necessary to use `\includegraphics [width = x]` inside the cells.

For example, you can do it successfully with the *paracol* package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}

\def\text{This is a text example inside a cell}

\columnratio{0.8}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\parbox[t][2cm][c]{\csname pcol@columnwidth\number1\endcsname}{\text}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `\hsize=\hsize` in `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hsize=\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}`?

Comment: Thanks @Mico. It was a bug in the MWE. It is not relevant for the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use \linewidth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\def\text{This is a text example inside a cell}

\newcommand{\cell}[2]{\parbox[t][#1][c]{\linewidth}{#2}}    % 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|C|}
\hline
\text & \cell{0.5\linewidth}{\text} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. I recommend this simple way of treatment height fixed tables.

Comment: \hsize also works

Answer (score 4):

Thinking outside of the box...

Hat tip to Phelype for clueing me in to both `\@wholewidth` and `\linethickness`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcount\cellwd
\newcount\cellsep
\cellwd=80
\cellsep=5
\makeatletter
%\linethickness{.1pt}
\newcommand\acell[1]{\noindent%
\framebox(\cellwd,\cellwd){\parbox{\the\numexpr\cellwd-\cellsep\relax pt}%
  {\centering#1}}\kern\@wholewidth\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\cellrowskip{\\[\dimexpr-1pt+\@wholewidth\relax]}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
What precedes.

\acell{Here is a test of my parbox}
\acell{xyz}
\acell{Not sure if this is what is desired}
\cellrowskip
\acell{Ha-ha!}
\acell{We are almost there!}
\acell{Finis!}

What follows.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a more packaged implementation, I introduce the syntax

```
\begin{celltable}[<linethickness>]{<cell width>}{<cell height>}{<2X cell sep>}
|{<cell data 1,1>} |{<cell-data 1,2>}
\cellrowskip
|{<cell data 2,1>} |{<cell-data 2,2>}
\end{celltable}
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcount\cellwd
\newcount\cellht
\newcount\cellsep
\makeatletter
{\catcode`|=\active \gdef|{\acell}}
\newcommand\acell[1]{\noindent%
\framebox(\cellwd,\cellht){\parbox{\the\numexpr\cellwd-\cellsep\relax pt}%
  {\centering#1}}\kern\@wholewidth\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\cellrowskip{\\[\dimexpr-1pt+\@wholewidth\relax]}
\newenvironment{celltable}[4][\@wholewidth]
{\cellwd=#2\relax
\cellht=#3\relax
\cellsep=#4\relax
\linethickness{#1}%
\vspace{#1}%
\par\catcode`\| \active 
}{\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
What precedes.

\begin{celltable}[3pt]{70}{50}{5}
|{Here is a test of my parbox}
|{xyz}
|{Not sure if this is what is desired}
\cellrowskip
|{Ha-ha!}
|{We are almost there!}
|{Finis!}
\end{celltable}

What follows.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\linethickness{...}` to change `\@wholewidth`

Comment: Thank you again, Phelype, for your assistance.

Comment: Yes, I had thought to consider another approaches like yours. But I prefer to stay within the tabular environment to use its powerfull features. Good answer, by the way.