# Calculate parskip based on number of lines in an address

Tags: parskip

Very new to LaTeX. Using the letter class, I need to line up the start of some text at a particular vertical position on the page - the first fold line on a letterpaper so the text is all inside the a z-fold.

I've managed to accomplish this by using the following which works well if address has 3 lines, however, if the address has only 2 lines I want to skip one extra paragraph to get the next bit of text in the right place. Basically I need some sort of command equivalent to 'make the address and the vertical space after equivalent to 5 lines'. Being new I'm not sure of what terms to search on.

```
% the opening
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\opening}[1]{\thispagestyle{firstpage}%
\xphvmn
\@letterdate\par
\@ourfile\par
{\raggedright\toname\\\toaddress\par}%
\vspace{2\parskip}% <-- if toaddress has 3 lines, this should be 2, if 2 lines then skip equivalent of 3 lines (to make up for the one less line)
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@subject}{}}{}{\@subject\par}
\xphvmn
\vspace{2\parskip}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why don't you use a minipage with fixed height (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56891/how-to-control-the-vertical-height-of-boxes)?

Comment: thank you @TeXnician - I had looked at minipage earlier but missed that they could handle a fixed height. This works much better and gives me some flexibility on a range of address sizes. I'll toy with the 2.0in till it's exactly the right amount.

Comment: Why don't you use `3\baselineskip`? And if it was an answer, you should put it as such (a question with an edited-in answer is kind of out-of-concept).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks TeXnician. Ended up with:

```
% the opening
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\opening}[1]{\thispagestyle{firstpage}%
\xphvmn
\@letterdate\par
\@ourfile\\
\begin{minipage}[c][2.0in]{\textwidth}
\raggedright\toname\\\toaddress
\end{minipage}
%\vspace{2\parskip}% <-- if address has 3 lines, this should be 2, if 2 lines then 3
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@subject}{}}{}{\raggedright\@subject\par}
\xphvmn
\vspace{2\parskip}%
}
\makeatother
```